# Writing SKLearn Regresion Coefficients To Pandas Series

Tags: pandas, numpy, series

I have a regression model that I fit in SKlearn's LinearRegression module:

To extract the coefficients, I used the code;

```
coefficients = model.coef_
```

It produced the following array with a shape of (1, 10):

```
[-4.72307152e-05  1.29731143e-04  8.75483702e-05 -6.28749019e-04
   1.75096740e-04 -3.30209379e-06  1.35937650e-03  3.89048429e-11
   8.48406857e-03 -1.36499030e-05]
```

Now, I would like to save the array to a pd.Series. I am taking the following approach:

```
features = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "f10"]
model_coefs = pd.Series(coefficients, index=features)
```

And, the system gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 10.
```

What I have tried:

- Transposing the underlying array, coefficients, to give it a length of 10.
- Reshaping the array to give it a shape of (10,1).

But nothing seems to work. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: There are no commas in between the values in your array, so it has shape 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you want to flatten the array so `.ravel` should do the trick for example:

```
pd.Series(np.zeros((1, 10)).ravel(), index=features)
```

It's strange the coeffs output are of shape `(1, 10)`, when I run the base sklearn example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) (with multiple features) my coeffs are of `1-d`:

```
In [27]: regr.coef_
Out[27]:
array([ 3.03499549e-01, -2.37639315e+02,  5.10530605e+02,  3.27736980e+02,
       -8.14131709e+02,  4.92814588e+02,  1.02848452e+02,  1.84606489e+02,
        7.43519617e+02,  7.60951722e+01])

In [28]: regr.coef_.shape
Out[28]: (10,)
```